# swfobject not communicating with html

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I'm having trouble trying to get swfobject embedded files to communicate with my html. When I embed swfs the the standard way using AC_RunActiveContent it works, any ideas why this would be ? Basically the navigation buttons along the bottom stop the swfs from playing when their clicked. I'd really appreciate any help!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
params.play = "true";
params.loop = "false";
params.menu = "true";
params.quality = "high";
params.scale = "showall";
params.wmode = "opaque";
params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";
params.devicefont = "false";
params.allowscriptaccess = "always";

var attributes = {};
swfobject.embedSWF("images/blank1.swf", "blank1", "747", "420", "9.0.0", flashvars, params, attributes);
swfobject.embedSWF("images/blank2.swf", "blank2", "747", "420", "9.0.0", flashvars, params, attributes);
swfobject.embedSWF("images/blank3.swf", "blank3", "747", "420", "9.0.0", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>


<script language="javascript">
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}

function stopFlash(){
    getFlashMovie("blank1").commandFlash();
    getFlashMovie("blank2").commandFlash();
    getFlashMovie("blank3").commandFlash();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="747" height="420">
    <param name="movie" value="images/blank1.swf" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="images/blank1.swf" width="747" height="420">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <img src="images/blank1.jpg" alt="" width="747px" height="420px" />
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
</div>

<div id="navigation">
<a href="#" name="btn" onClick="stopFlash()"><div id="slideshow-previous"></div></a>
<a href="#" name="btn" onClick="stopFlash()"><div id="slideshow-next"></div></a>
<a href="#" name="btn" onClick="stopFlash()"><div id="slideshow-first"></div></a>
</div>
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 1):

In your SWF, have you imported flash.external.ExternalInterface?

If not, you'll need to do that and then also expose the 'commandFlash' method in your SWF. You may need to allow this kind of communication on your domain, too.

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

System.security.allowDomain('*');
var flashAvailable:Boolean = ExternalInterface.available;

ExternalInterface.addCallback('commandFlash', null, commandFlash);
function commandFlash( args... ){
  //
}
```

Other than the above, perhaps your SWF is hidden with display:none; on the page at some point, and then revealed? This has caused some strangeness for me in Firefox in the past.

(not sure if you're using AS2/3 in your SWF)

Comment: Hi Danjah, thanks for your reply, I am using AS3 and have imported flash.external.ExternalInterface in my swfs. The swfs 'stop' when the buttons are clicked when I embed the swf the 'standard' way (using the published code), but when I use swfobject they don't.

Comment: What gets returned when you test for coms availability with the SWFs? Or can you not even get that out of the SWF? Gots a URL I can have a peek at?

Comment: I knew I was out of my depth! - SO much to learn still! I'm not sure what coms availability is (sorry). I do have a URL but as the site isn't mine I'm a little reluctant to post a link. It worked fine with AC_RunActiveContent but I couldn't get a 'replacement' image to display if the end user didn't have flash so I'd thought I'd use swfobject instead, which seems to have caused more problems than I initially had!

Comment: If you want to send just me a link, danjah + @ + gmail.com, otherwise by "coms availability" I meant can you contact the SWF to see if ExternalInterface is available? Perhaps just alert("EI available: "+getFlashMovie("blank1").ExternalInterface.available). Or before that, maybe just qualify that getFlashMovie() is actually finding what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Your SWFObject code has errors: it's missing the express install parameter.

```
swfobject.embedSWF("images/blank1.swf", "blank1", "747", "420", "9.0.0", "expressinstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
swfobject.embedSWF("images/blank2.swf", "blank2", "747", "420", "9.0.0", "expressinstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
swfobject.embedSWF("images/blank3.swf", "blank3", "747", "420", "9.0.0", "expressinstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Of course you need to replace "expressinstall.swf" with the correct path to your expressinstall.swf file. If you don't want to use express install, just put a `false` boolean instead.

```
swfobject.embedSWF("images/blank1.swf", "blank1", "747", "420", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
swfobject.embedSWF("images/blank2.swf", "blank2", "747", "420", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
swfobject.embedSWF("images/blank3.swf", "blank3", "747", "420", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted - managed to work it out (see below) thanks to everyone for their input/support!
Only problem now is internet explorer is returning an error "object doesn't support this property or method" on the buttons that fire the stopFlash command, but at least it still works. Grrr.

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {wmode:"opaque", allowscriptaccess:"always" };
var attributes = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("images/clients/blank1.swf", "blank1", "747", "420", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
swfobject.embedSWF("images/clients/blank2.swf", "blank2", "747", "420", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
swfobject.embedSWF("images/clients/blank3.swf", "blank3", "747", "420", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);


function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}


function stopFlash(){
getFlashMovie("blank1").commandFlash();
getFlashMovie("blank2").commandFlash();
getFlashMovie("blank3").commandFlash();
return true;
}
```